# PHP Excel jump to next page

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using `php excel` to export my products and products detail in `xlsx`, i am   using `foreach` loop to export above data , i want to show one product with detail at one page then if more then one product move next product to next page.

Comment: by "page", do you mean "worksheet"? Or are you talking about setting printer options in your xlsx file?

Comment: My mean to say move to next page but not create new worksheet in same worksheet jump to next page suppose product 1 on page 1/5 and product 2 on page 2/5 and product 3 on page 3/5 and so on..

Comment: Then use something like `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak( 'A10' , PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );` to set page breaks (in this case, at row 10)